# meaning of "right with"

Tags: word-meaning

> Pope  Gregory  XIII wanted to make a better plan. It  was  easy  to  take  10  days  away  from  the  calendar.  This  made  it  **right  with**  the  sun  again. There was still a problem: how to keep the calendar right in the future, year after year.

In this paragraph, what does "right with" mean?
Does it mean "without delay" or " at the same rate of the sun"?

Comment: Basically, yes. That is because the calendar is a solar calendar (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_calendar), which means it is in harmony with the position of the sun (or “right with the sun“).

Comment: To syncronize the calendar and the sun.

Answer (score 3):

It's using **right** to mean **correct** and assumes that the reader will infer the context to be **the position of the sun in the sky** (the solar date) from "with the sun".

Therefore, the sentence doesn't quite mean what you propose, it means that **the calendar date was [synchronised](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synchronise) with the solar date** (e.g. a [solstice](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/solstice) or [equinox](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equinox) being on the correct date in the calendar).

The sentence afterwards makes it clear that they hadn't (yet) fixed the problem of the calendar date going out of sync with the solar date, so not (yet) "at the same rate".

---

For information: **[without delay](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/without%20delay)** is used to mean **immediately** or **now** (using delay as a verb), *not* "with no delay between two things" (e.g. calendars or clocks). For that meaning you would say "without **a** delay" (using delay as a noun). E.g.

> I'll set my watch without delay. - means I'll set my watch **now**
>
> I'll set my watch without **a** delay. - means I'll set my watch **to the correct time**